# Reindex a removed domain in google search console (DNS changed)

Tags: google-search-console

My website was indexed in the Google search engine by a company. A few days ago I changed my server hosting company and transferred my domain it.

They may have removed my site, or blocked it, or changed something in Google Search Console. I had added my website to Google Search Console like other websites (a week ago) and in Google search console I see that website is indexed but its not showing in search results (site:www.-----.com). Help!!! :)

Notes:

1) In the admin panel i can still see the performance of my website for the last year.

2) My website was developed on WordPress CMS and now its a simple website not CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you [verified your Google Search Console account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) with **HTML tag** or **Domain name provider** option and that's why you couldn't access it once you changed the server and the site.

Nonetheless, although you changed the hosting (or DNS) Google should not have had any problem indexing your domain. Verify with [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) tool that your site is visible to Google crawler.

Just as a reminder, make sure you migrated the old Wordpress version to the new site using a `301 redirect` in case URLs changed.